# How to set various attribute of DOM element from variable angular 2?

Tags: dom, angular, element

In my app I have variable of String. Which is have in string name of attribute to add.

```
ngOnInit()
{
   this.colAttibute = 'width-50';
}
```

or it can be equal to 'width-100'. My app is get device width and set the value of this variable on onNgInit method.
I want to set this attribute to my html code something like that:

```
<ion-list no-lines *ngIf="list">
  <ion-list-header>
    Лидеры продаж
  </ion-list-header>
  <ion-item class="categoryProductItem" *ngFor="let row of list;">
      <ion-row wrap >
        <ion-col *ngFor="let product of row" $colAttibute > <!--Here must be width-50 or width-100 attribute-->
          <a ion-item detail-push (click)="onSelectItem(product)" >
            <div class="categoryProductItemImage" *ngIf="product.getMainImage()">
                <ion-img [src]="product.getMainImage()['small_url']"></ion-img>
            </div>
            <h2>
              {{product.title}}
            </h2>
          </a>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the width like this:

```
<ion-col [attr.width-70]="flag">
```

Where flag is a boolean value indicating whether to apply this attribute or not.
Unfortunately, you will need to list all the available attributes in order to support all of them dynamically.

Comment: Note: To get the attribute removed the `flag` needs to be set to `null`. `false` doesn't remove it.

Comment: Do I may can somehow use "this" in template?